# How to create a .pfx certificate from a .cer whitout the private key?

Tags: ssl-certificate, azure-web-app-service, pfx

I would like to import an SSL certificate on an Microsoft Azure Website.

I generated the .csr request file using the windows command "certreq" direclty on mylaptop (not on the server).

I retrieved an CER certificate using this .csr file.

But know I'm blocked, the Azure websites page wants a .pfx file and refuse the .cer file.

I tried to use www.sslshopper.com to transform my .cer certificate into a .pfx file but it needs the private key...

So Here are my questions :
 * Can I transform a .cer to .pfx without a the private key ?
 * how can I get the private key used by the certreq command of my laptop ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I known, `certreq` would store your private keys in your certificate store when it generates CSRs. And you need to finish the certificate request on the same computer where you generated the CSR request. There is [issue](https://serverfault.com/questions/717178/where-is-the-private-key-after-using-certreq-for-csr-generation-on-windows-10) about finding the private key after using `certreq` for CSR generation.

Based on your description, you could follow this [tutorial](https://pubs.vmware.com/horizon-7-view/index.jsp#com.vmware.horizon-view.certificates.doc/GUID-18C54A6F-CD54-48DF-8FD4-870417274539.html) to import your signed certificate into the windows local computer certificate store by using certreq, then click "Start > Run", type `certmgr.msc` to manage computer certificates, right click the certificate root node and choose "Find Certificates" to find your certificate as follows:

[image]

Click export your certificate, choose the option "export the private key", then export your certificate to .pfx file. Also, you could leverage [DigiCertUtil](https://www.digicert.com/util/pfx-certificate-management-utility-import-export-instructions.htm) to export your certificates.

Additionally, for more flexibility over your private key than `certreq`, you could use OpenSSL command line tool to generate your private keys and your certificate signing request instead of certreq. Also, for a simple way, you could use this GUI tool [startcomtool](https://objects.startpki.net/installonserver/How%20to%20use%20startcomtool.pdf) to generate your CSR and export the certificates.

Comment: Finally I re started the process from the beginning using OpenSSL because I was not available to find the imported certificate on my laptop...

Answer (score 0):

You need to associate private key with issued certificate. Depending on context used in certreq (current user or local machine context) run appropriate command:

```
certreq -user -accept path\certfile.cer
```

Or

```
certreq -accept path\certfile.cer
```

Comment: Ok but how can I transform the .cer file into .pfx file after this command? The Private Key is in the file itself ?

Comment: when you associate the key with certificate, export certificate to PFX from certificate store.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what I need to do. In azure website, I do not have a prompt to make command, I can only upload the PFX file.